# Why won't the data in the model persist?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a model, `MyViewModel`, with some members (not all are included).

```
namespace ANameSpace
{
    public class MyViewModel
    {
       public int ID { get; set }
       public EditTableObject EditTable { get; set }
       public List<EditTableObject> EditTables { get; set }
       // some other members
    }

    public class EditTableObject
    {
       public int ID { get; set }
       // some other members
    }
}
```

In the controller there are two ActionResult Index() methods

In The first, Index(int? id), I assign a value to model.ID and also add some EditTableObjects to an EditTables list.

Then, in the second, Index(ViewModel tmpModel), I am trying to use the members that I gave values to in the first index method. However, the ID member does not contain the value I assigned it; it's null. But strangely, the EditTables list does contain the values I assigned to it.

Here is some code from the controller:

```
namespace AnotherNamespace
{
   public class MyController
   {
      public ActionResult Index(int? id)
      {
         if (id != null)
         {
            model.ID = (int)id;
         }
         else
         {
            model.ID = 1000;
         }


         model.EditTable = new EditTableObject();

         model.EditTable.ID = model.ID;

         model.EditTables.Add(model.EditTable);

         return View(model);
      }

      public ActionResult(MyViewModel tmpModel)
      {
         return RedirectToAction("Index", new { id = tmpModel.ID });
      }
   } 
}
```

If I set a break point on the second Index method I find that all the EditTables data persists but not the model.ID data.

Why is the EditTables data persisting but not the model.ID data?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: How are you getting from Index(int? id) to Index(ViewModel tmpModel)?  Are you posting back to Index?  If so, I need to see your form code to determine why it's not binding to model.ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.

In the the Razor View I added `@Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ID)` to a table row. 
Here it is in more context:

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.EditTables.Count; i++)
   {    
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.EditTables[i].ID)
            @Html.HiddenFor(modelItem => Model.ID)
        </td>
    </tr>
    }
```

Sorry for my lack of code in the beginning. I work for a company that would not be happy I shared code on the internet so I have to pick and choose and be careful what I post.

Answer (score 0):

Eventhough I don't quite get your question (posting some code that doesn't work will highly improve your chances of getting an answer) I'll give it a shot.

HttpRequests are stateless. So between the calls to the different methods you need to persist your data. Usually that's been done using a database.

This is a good source to get started with MVC: http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Then why does the EditTables data persist. E.g., I can get a Count of EditTableObjects from the controller.

Comment: Please show us some code, else any answer will just be guesswork.

Comment: Okay. Please hold on.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not giving the entire model.

In order to receive the model you need to set your view based on that model and pass it to the controller on httppost.

Example

**Controller**

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<EditTableObject> myList = ....*YourList*....
        ViewBag.EditTables = myList;
        ViewModel vm = new ViewModel();
        return View(vm);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(ViewModel myViewModel)
    {
        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
          // DO SOMETHING
        }
        else
        {
            return View(myViewModel);
        }
     }
```

**View**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<namespace.ViewModel>" %>
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%: Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
    <%: Html.ValidationSummary(true) %>

        <%: Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID) %>

        <div class="editor-field">
            <%: Html.DropDownList("TableObject", IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.EditTable,String.Empty)%>
        </div>
<% } %>
```

Comment: I'm redirecting post to the other index method rather returning the view.